# Create stored procedure with table from another schema throws PLS-00201

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Oracle 10g. I'm new to procedures, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Schema owner ABC has table T2001_WRITEOFF.  First I had granted SIUD to some_update_role, and granted that role to developer user IJK.  User IJK then created synonym  T2001_WRITEOFF for ABC.T2001_WRITEOFF;  This worked with normal SQL DML commands.

However, I read elsewhere on here that grants via a role do not work in stored procedures. I dropped the synonym from IJK; then from ABC, granted SIUD directly to IJK.  From IJK, normal SQL DML works.

When I try to create a simple procedure as follows, it throws PLS-00201 identifier 'T2001_WRITEOFF' must be declared, and points to the 2nd line. This error is the same whether I use the role grants or not.

```
create or replace procedure woof1(
    fooname in T2001_WRITEOFF.territory%TYPE,  <=== error points here
    bardesc IN T2001_WRITEOFF.ind_batch_submit%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    INSERT into T2001_WRITEOFF
    VALUES ( fooname, bardesc);
END woof1;
/
```

Thanks in advance for help

JimR

Comment: If you have dropped the synonym `T2001_WRITEOFF.territory%TYPE` will not work. Try `ABC.T2001_WRITEOFF.territory%TYPE` instead.

Comment: Nope, sorry, same results.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make role right applicable in stored procedures you might want to look at `authid current_user` in the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/sqlexamples.htm#TTPLS394). Also helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS682

Comment: Nope, sorry, tried authid current_user as well as authid definer, but both produced the same error.