# Error -359 SQL Function (function stored procedure) not found - In ODBC query through Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, odbc

I've been working on some new projects involving queries through an Excel ODBC connection. In the last couple days I've been getting a '-359 SQL Function (function stored procedure) not found' for multiple functions that I know are written correctly.

I'm very new with ODBC queries from a live DB, and I'm hoping someone can explain to me why basic functions do not work, and if there is a way I can get them to by creating a UDF or something like that at the beginning of the query or in Excel itself. Here's a snippet of code that I know otherwise works fine, but won't work in the ODBC query

Unfortunately, the company who runs the DB still won't tell me version of Oracle's SQL the DB is on, but I've tried even the most basic of built in functions like CONCAT to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TABLE frequencies
    ([Patient_Num] int, [Frequency] varchar(10))
;
    
INSERT INTO frequencies
    ([Patient_Num], [Frequency])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (1, 'B'),
    (2, 'A')
;

select Patient_Num,
    string_agg(Frequency, '; ') as Frequencies
    from frequencies 
    group by Patient_Num
```

Comment: Been awhile since I've used Oracle, but they might not need to tell you the version, you may be able to query `SELECT * FROM v$version;` to find out.

Comment: I've tried. Unfortunately it won't work because my only access to the server is through an Excel ODBC connection and it wont support that query, or anything else concerning the version - I'm guessing... because it's not data that Microsoft can filter into their Power Query M fields

Comment: Some of [this checklist for tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48907533/230471) also applies to functions. Are you connecting as the user that owns the function? If not, are you granted execute privilege, is there a synonym, etc? (Edit: also see [this checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44283970/230471).

Comment: I think you're on to something with privileges, William. I don't know what my privileges are. Some context, I'm accessing a medical db from an outside agency so I think they're pretty strict about permissions when it comes to manipulating data instead of just querying for it, but unfortunately, they won't answer any of my questions. That's why I'm wondering too if a UDF would maybe work at the beginning of the query?

Comment: You should be able to query `user_tab_privs_recd` for privileges granted to your user, and `role_tab_privs` for permissions granted to any roles you have (and just for fun, `role_role_privs` for roles granted to roles you have).